# Lambda trigger lag through DynamoDB streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

**Assumption:**

lets assume rate of data insertion into DynamoDB is huge.

**Context:**

Streams are enabled on DynamoDB table and this will trigger lambda. The lambda reads the streamed record and indexes the record in elastic search.

**Problem statement:**

There is a delay between the time that record got inserted into DynamoDB and the time lambda got triggered through streamed record. This delay or lag kept increasing and is directly proportional to the amount of data getting inserted into dynamoDB.

How to find where the lag is? Is it the stream is not immediately triggering the lambda? or as there are huge dynamo writes the stream is getting hampered? or is there any limit that lambda could not be hit for certain number of times in a given second?

I couldn't understand where the issue is because I could not even see whether currently the streams still contains records OR the records in streams have already been delivered but lambda trigger is the lag?

Example delay:
We did huge writes yesterday and we are seeing those records hitting the lambda today! incredible delay! :)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you looking at the monitoring tab for lambda? You should see the IteratorAge, the execution time, concurrent invocations.  What is the average execution time?

Comment: There are concurrent invocations that are upto 4.6k but yeah those spike are not like consistent but yeah I am seeing enough spikes ranging from 800 - 4.6k.
*****

And iterator age going upto 43M to 110M
****
Duration avg is hitting 30k to 300k

Comment: The execution time is the problem. First you can try increasing the memory for lambda, but you also need to look at other ways to lower the execution time. Also make sure that that you don't have partitions with large number of items.

Comment: I think I figured out. The amount of triggers to the lambda are huge and the iteratorAge went super high. We need to optimize the lambda so that it becomes available for all those thats in-coming

Answer (score 2):

From [Lambda Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html)

> For Lambda functions that process Kinesis or DynamoDB streams the
>   number of shards is the unit of concurrency. If your stream has 100
>   active shards, there will be at most 100 Lambda function invocations
>   running concurrently. This is because Lambda processes each shard’s
>   events in sequence.

The logic of creating shard is not exposed to end user. But it is dependent on your 
[RSU and WSUs.](https://blog.codeship.com/partitioning-behavior-of-dynamodb/) But increasing them too much will cost you money.

On the Top of this, there is a limit on concurrent lambda par account. Depending on your region of operation (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html) ).

Here are few things that you can do

1. Make Sure that While ingesting data in dynamodb you are using random PK instead of some ordered PK, so that probability of hitting different shard is increased.
2. Make Sure you are reusing connection to Elastic Search while ingesting data.
3. Increase the batch size so that multiple records can be ingested by same lambda function. [see **Batch size** here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html)
4. Use scripting language instead of java for reducing cold start issues.
5. See if there are other lambdas that are running and you are hitting the max concurrent limit of lambda (It should be highly unlikely.)

Comment: 1. My PK is UUID
2. I am not even worrying about indexing/ number of connections to ES because that lambda where we index into ES itself has huge lag.
3. Batch size has been increased from 100 to 1000 already!
4. We use Python 3.7
5. Yeah its unlikely!

Comment: increasing from 100 to 1000 will also contribute to lag since now your queue will wait till it has 1000 records, which may take some time since you are using uuid, hence it is a bad idea

Comment: is it true? does it wait to get 1000? I expect it to send 1000 if there are 1000 or else whatever is available. What you said is true then I should have saw a stream lambda event with 1000 records. That was never the case

Comment: ```The number of records to read from a shard in each batch, up to 1,000. Lambda passes all of the records in the batch to the function in a single call, as long as the total size of the events doesn't exceed the payload limit for synchronous invocation (6 MB).``` hence you would be hitting 6mb limit instead of 1000, just decrease from 1000 to 1 and see if you are getting events instantaniously.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but eventhough the batchSize is set to 1000, in the lambda event, I never saw event containing records more than 5 (max).

Comment: Hi, can you have a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020731/lambda-runs-multiple-times-with-dynamodb-trigger